# Postfix alias for all user names?

Tags: linux, unix, gnu, postfix-mta

Is there something you can put in /etc/aliases that will make postfix send all mail to one user, no matter what the username?

Comment: Check out serverfault.com for sysadmin questions, where this question has already been answered. <https://serverfault.com/questions/23717/postfix-how-do-you-redirect-all-emails-to-one-user-eg-example-com-userexa>